# How to literally translate this: 第二种忙，忙得很主动，忙而不乱，人是工作的主人？

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

工作中的忙碌大概可以分为三种：第一种忙， ...；第二种忙，忙得很主动，忙而不乱，人是工作的主人；第三种忙，...

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 26. I want your help for the literal translation of this:

第二种忙，忙得很主动，忙而不乱，人是工作的主人

第二(second)种(kind of)忙(busyness)，忙(busyness)得很(very)主动(?)，忙(busyness)而(?)不(not)乱(chaotic)，人(people)是(are)工作的(work's)主人(?)

As you can see there are 3 words that I don't understand what they mean in this context.

1. 主动：active, proactive, self-motivated, self-starting?
2. 而：and, but, to?
3. 主人：master, owner, expert?

How to make it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

第二种**忙** - The second type of **busyness**(n),

**忙**得很主动 - **busy**(adj) at the proactive level (proactively busy oneself)

**忙**而不乱 - **busy**(adj) but not chaotic,

人是工作的主人. - The person is the master of his work (the person is managing his workload)

Note:

*忙得很被动 - busy at the reactive level (works are forced upon the person)*

Comment: What does 主动 = at the proactive level mean here? At the preemptive level or at the dynamic level?

Comment: should be  dynamic level --> a person takes the initiative to do something, vs. being told  to do something